# terraform creating duplicate dns validation records

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53

I'm new to Terraform, but my route53 file looks like this...

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = var.domain_name
  tags = var.common_tags
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "root-a" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name = var.domain_name
  type = "A"

  alias {
    name = aws_cloudfront_distribution.root_s3_distribution.domain_name
    zone_id = aws_cloudfront_distribution.root_s3_distribution.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www-a" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name = "www.${var.domain_name}"
  type = "A"

  alias {
    name = aws_cloudfront_distribution.www_s3_distribution.domain_name
    zone_id = aws_cloudfront_distribution.www_s3_distribution.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert-validations" {
  count = length(aws_acm_certificate.ssl_certificate.domain_validation_options)
  
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = element(aws_acm_certificate.ssl_certificate.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_name, count.index)
  type    = element(aws_acm_certificate.ssl_certificate.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_type, count.index)
  records = [element(aws_acm_certificate.ssl_certificate.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_value, count.index)]
  ttl     = 60
}
```

my plan contains this duplicate...

```
  # aws_route53_record.cert-validations[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "cert-validations" {
      + allow_overwrite = (known after apply)
      + fqdn            = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = "_0a4aefbce6d554a924845eec429fb23e.gingerbreadtemplate.uk"
      + records         = [
          + "_8392f4358688e2d691acfe88deecb4f6.xjncphngnr.acm-validations.aws.",
        ]
      + ttl             = 60
      + type            = "CNAME"
      + zone_id         = "Z068604727JU0L259KARW"
    }

  # aws_route53_record.cert-validations[1] will be created
  + resource "aws_route53_record" "cert-validations" {
      + allow_overwrite = (known after apply)
      + fqdn            = (known after apply)
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = "_0a4aefbce6d554a924845eec429fb23e.gingerbreadtemplate.uk"
      + records         = [
          + "_8392f4358688e2d691acfe88deecb4f6.xjncphngnr.acm-validations.aws.",
        ]
      + ttl             = 60
      + type            = "CNAME"
      + zone_id         = "Z068604727JU0L259KARW"
    }
```

This then fails when it is applied. If i set the `cert-validations.count` to `1` it works but I think this is a hack. Could it be because I'm setting up a redirection hosted zone too, so the number of validations overall is 2 but my code isn't clever enough?

I've tried to read the examples and the docs but I'm really struggling to understand where the duplication is coming from.

Comment: "then fails when it is applied" - is not clear. What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplication might come from the definition of the `aws_acm_certificate`:

```
domain_name = "gingerbreadtemplate.uk"
subject_alternative_names = [
  "gingerbreadtemplate.uk"
]
```

If the code defines a SAN with the same value than the domain name, the validation records that it generates afterwards will be duplicated.

Also as this code seems to be Terraform 0.12+, it would be easier to read the code with a `for_each` block for the [validation records](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate#referencing-domain_validation_options-with-for_each-based-resources). It also avoids ordering issues that comes with count if a new SAN is added in the middle of other ones.